# SQL how to drop rows based on values from two columns

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a SQL query result I would love to clean up, the query result is following

| NAME | OPT_IN |
| --- | --- |
| JOHN | TRUE |
| JOHN | FALSE |
| KEK | TRUE |

and now I want to  select `| JOHN | FALSE |` when `| JOHN | TRUE |`

edit: adding the expected result, and fixed a few wordings with more correct terms

| NAME | OPT_IN |
| --- | --- |
| JOHN | FALSE |
| KEK | TRUE |

The way I have tried is highly inefficient, I first get all the columns with `TRUE` and all the columns with `FALSE` and then post processing them using Python.

Comment: Do you want to actually delete the rows, or just remove them from a query?

Comment: remove from query, it wasn't worded correctly, apologies

Comment: @kemoosabee what is the expected result for the given data example ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha edited the post to add expected result, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple delete statement for this. First filter for all records where `opt_in` is true, then use `EXISTS` to also filter for those that also have a corresponding false record. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE t (name varchar(5), opt_in bit);
INSERT INTO t (name, opt_in) VALUES ('John', 1),('John', 0),('kek', 1);

DELETE t1
FROM   t AS t1
WHERE  t1.opt_in =1
AND    EXISTS 
       (   SELECT  1 
           FROM    (SELECT * FROM t) AS t2 
           WHERE   t2.name =t1.name 
           AND     t2.opt_in = 0
       );
```

<sub>Note the subquery (`(SELECT * FROM t)`) in the exists is due to a limitation in MySQL about referencing the same table you are deleting from directly in the where clause, so a further level of nesting is required to get around this.</sub>

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OL9W-DtV)**

### ADDENDUM

If you just want to perform this filter in a select, you can still use exists (or not exists to be more precise), you just need to rearrange the logic slightly:

```
SELECT  t1.name, t1.opt_in
FROM    t AS t1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS 
        (   SELECT 1 
            FROM    t AS t2 
            WHERE   t2.name = t1.name 
            AND     t2.opt_in = 0 
            AND     t1.opt_in = 1
        );
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wBAIUFFT)**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense to me now

Answer (score 1):

We can retrieve the ones with both *FALSE* and *TRUE* values using `GROUP BY`, `MIN` and `MAX`, the condition is that there is at least one record with "opt_in" set to *FALSE* and at least one record set to *TRUE* :

```
SELECT name
FROM mytable
GROUP BY name
HAVING MIN(opt_in) = FALSE AND MAX(opt_in) = TRUE;
```

Then we join the table with this dataset, and remove the matched entries :

```
DELETE t 
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT name
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY name
      HAVING MIN(opt_in) = FALSE AND MAX(opt_in) = TRUE
) AS s ON s.name = t.name
WHERE t.opt_in = TRUE;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/3lRE7xNr)

Answer (score 0):

You may use this delete query.

```
delete from table_name where (column1, column2) = (select column1, TRUE from table_name where <here is your condition to return JOHN/false records>)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a window function. This is likely to be more efficient than the other options which do a self-join**

Either just sort and take the top 1 per group

```sql
SELECT
  t.name,
  t.opt_in
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.name ORDER BY t.opt_in) AS countFalse
    FROM t
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

Or a conditional count.

```sql
SELECT
  t.name,
  t.opt_in
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN t.opt_in = 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY t.name) AS countFalse
    FROM t
) t
WHERE (t.opt_in = 0 OR t.countFalse = 0);
```